# Distinguishing Clauses

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, adverbial-phrases

> It was 1994, and **when her baby daughter would fall asleep**, Rowling would stroll her to a cafe that was close to her home.

In this sentence, what kind of clause is the clause "when her baby daughter would fall asleep"?

Comment: Note:  **would fall asleep** and **would stroll**.  This means that it was Rowling's *normal practice* to take the sleeping baby in a pram to a cafe. It was something she did *regularly*, not just once.

Answer (score 1):

> when her baby daughter would fall asleep

is a subordinate [temporal](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/temporal.htm) clause introduced by the subordinate conjunction **when**.

Answer (score 0):

The scene was set in 1994, but it requires further fine tuning indicating temporal sequence introduced by time subordinator WHEN. SO,

'When the baby daughter would fall asleep...'

states the circumstances or situation of the coordinate clause in relation to which it has got its relevance:

..., Rowling would stroll her to a cafe...

The when clause here indicates the  temporal visibility of time and helps situate the event of "strolling". It is an "Existential When".  It is an adverb clause of time to show time relationship. When is just a subordinating conjunction and belongs to the same category as of " after, while, before,by the time, since " etc.